# Simplex in convex polytope, pulling triangulation

Tags: convex-polytopes, triangulations

Let $P$ be a convex $d$-dimensional polytope. 
I have two questions, related to triangulations of $P$.

*Question 1:*
Let $p$ be in the interior of $P$. Can I always find a triangulation of $P$,
such that the (or some, if not unique) $d$-dim simplex $S$ that contains $p$,
has the property that $S$ intersects the boundary of $P$, such that the intersection has same dimension as the boundary of the simplex.

*The triangulation should not add any additional vertices:*
each simplex in the triangulation must have vertices in $P$.

I think this is the property of the triangulation I wish to prove:
*A triangulation of $P$ is **nice** if every $k$-dim simplex in the triangulation has a $k-1$-dimensional intersection with a $k$-dimensional face of $P$.*

*Question 2:* There is the notion of "pulling triangulation",
[used here by Stanley](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan//pubs/pubfiles/40.pdf), which is a special type of triangulation.
I suspect that this triangulation is nice, but I dont know how to prove this.

I suspect this property of the triangulation is very natural, and has most likely been studied before, so I seek some reference for this.

EDIT: For the first question, it is the same as follows:

We know that since $P$ is convex, every $p \in P$ can always be expressed as 
$$p = a_1p_1 + \dots + a_d p_d$$ for some $p_i \in P$ and $a_i>0$ and $\sum a_i=1$.
Question 1 is equivalent to that we can always choose the $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_{d-1}$
to be vertices in a face of $P$.

Comment: For Q1, couldn't you triangulate so that $p$ is a vertex of every simplex, a star triangulation centered at $p$, with each simplex the hull of a facet with $p$?

Comment: Ah, right, I want that the triangulation do not add additional vertices, I should add that.

Comment: How about a star triangulation centered at some vertex $q$ of $P$ then (triangulate each face not containing $q$ and use the corresponding simplexes as bases; it looks like now *every* simplex has good intersection with the boundary)?

Comment: @fedja: Ah, yes, this is what my intuition tells me; is it obvious that this works? It is, right? I think the pulling triangulation of Stanley is a special case of iterated star triangulation, so, it seems to work in this case also. Is this "common knowledge" that these properties hold, or are there references for this?

Comment: What fedja is describing is (a version of) the pulling triangulation, and indeed has the following "nice" property: "Every $k$-dim simplex in a pulling triangulation has (at least) a facet (that is, a $(k-1)$-dim face) contained in the boundary of $P$."

Comment: However, there is something wrong in your detailed definition of nice: "A triangulation of $P$ is nice if every $k$-dim simplex in the triangulation has a $k−1$-dimensional intersection with a $k$-dimensional face of P". This property, as written, fails for every $d$-simplex...

Comment: @FranciscoSantos: Ok, so every k-dim simplex should have at least one $k-1$-dimensional face which is not in the interior of $P$.

Comment: Pulling triangulations actually go back to Hudson, *Piecewise Linear Topology*, 1969, Lemma 1.4, and were used by various other researchers before me.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling triangulations have these properties, and it is quite easy from the construction to see this.